# Unable to add/display button

Tags: javascript, html

start button and stop button have similar properties which i have given to restart button.

I am new to JavaScript so kindly give me a detailed explanation.

```js
//Restart Test
const restartTest = () => {
  // Reset variables
  mistakes = 0;
  timer = "";
  time = 60;
  
  // Reset UI
  userInput.disabled = false;
  userInput.value = "";
  document.getElementById("start-test").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("stop-test").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector(".result").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("mistakes").innerText = "0";
  document.getElementById("timer").innerText = "60s";
  document.getElementById("wpm").innerText = "0 wpm";
  document.getElementById("accuracy").innerText = "0 %";

  
  renderNewQuote();
};

window.onload = () => {
  userInput.value = "";
  document.getElementById("start-test").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("stop-test").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("restart-test").style.display = "none"; // Hide restart button initially
  userInput.disabled = true;
  renderNewQuote();

  
  document.getElementById("restart-test").addEventListener("click", restartTest);
};
```

```html
      <button id="start-test" onclick="startTest()">Start Test</button>
      <button id="stop-test" onclick="displayResult()">Stop Test</button>
      <button id="restart-test" onclick="restartTest()">Restart Test</button>
```

In the restart test section i am repeatedly facing same issue of not getting the Restart Button displayed.

Comment: `document.getElementById("restart-test").style.display = "none";` - But nowhere in the code you have written something to actually display the button?

Comment: PS: use rather `textContent` instead of `innerText`. Avoid using `display =` from JavaScript. The easiest is to set a `data-state=""` to your body Element, and style in CSS as necessary like `[data-state="init"] #start-test { display: none; }` and finally there's no need to reset to `block` and other silly stuff, since once you change the `data-state` attribute (via JS) the CSS will be appropriately resetted to the element's default styles.

Comment: Side note - you don't have to define onlick in html if you already have addEventListener for it at js.

Comment: Additionally, inline `onclick` attribute handlers in HTML (same goes for `style` without CSS variables) is sign of poor coding habit. (as stated by :szgoon) use `addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: this isnt the complete code i had written display button but still was not able to display it. I will now implement the changes and check the code. Thank you everyone.